# What is the Chrome "System Profile"?

Tags: google-chrome

Looking in the Chrome data directory (`~/.config/google-chrome`), I see that there's a `System Profile` subdir which hasn't been touched in about a month, and with many less (and smaller) files than in the `Default` subdir which has my main profile.  So, what exactly is the purpose of the System Profile?

I'm using stable Chrome (v 54.0.2840.90) on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=482176#c12:

> The System Profile is a built-in-with-Chrome profile that backs the User Manager. It is not used by users for actual browsing; it provides a Profile for the User Manager (switch person window) only.